# change frame height after the EGOTextView is Created

Tags: iphone, richtextbox

I'm trying to use EGOTextView in iphone dev, I want to change the height by code after the EGOTextView is created, I tried setFrame or frame = newframe, both aren't work, could you give some advice.

Best,

rosone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the whole frame of `EGOTextView` (the position and size), then use:

```
EGOTextView.frame = CGRectMake(new x, new y, new width, new height);
```

If you only want to change the size, then use:

```
EGOTextView.size = CGSizeMake(new width, new height);
```

Each "new" object above should be a number (e.g. `CGSizeMake(320, 480)`).

Comment: I thought it's this problem, but it's not. this code is passed, but xcode 4.3 said here is a problem.... xcode doesn't locate the error exact place...